# Where can I find existing pre-trained torch models?

Tags: neural-network, torch, nvidia-digits

I'm using Torch 7 and lua 5.1. I will need to do object recognition from an input video stream. I've installed DIGITS from NVidia.
I've heard there are existing models that are already pre-trained provided by Google (or someone other source).  Where I can find them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to check https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Model-Zoo it is a common GitHub repo with a bunch of trained models. Even though it is made for caffe framework there is a library (really easy to use) in torch that lets you use them without problems: https://github.com/szagoruyko/loadcaffe